# How do you create online Audio Converting website?

Tags: encode, backend, frontend

My question is not specific to the title as such. I am not able to clearly express what I want to do in the title, so it's a generalization of the ideas.

I want to run a website that gathers data from user. Say, something like Audio file, e.g. *Hello.mp3*.

I would like to convert this Mp3 file into Wav by using a software on the PC, like Any Audio converter and after the conversion, I wish to upload it back to the webserver so that at frontend the user will be able to download the song easily.

Well my purpose is a little different from what I wish to say. At school we have some astronomical software, and our professor says that they are proprietary for our school. And I wish the other users to upload their data in form of Excel files that our Astro software may convert on the backend and process the information and back again upload the processed information to the Web user.

How is it possible and what are the things that I need to study?

Also let me know the technical prerequisites for such programming tasks.

Comment: Does this software run on Linux or Windows?